# Chrome Extension - Grabbing link from Reddit post after upvoting

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I"m trying to make a chrome extension. One of the functions of the extension is to grab the link of the post that the user has upvoted. I'm a little confused on how to go about it...

This what I have gotten to work on it so far as far as testing is:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.matches('.arrow.upmod')) {
        alert("Hi");
    }
});
```

Which just displays "Hi" when you click the upvote button. I was just testing to see if it actually detects the vote change.

I was playing around with some jQuery, and if you write:

```
$('div .arrow').parent().parent()
```

you get the  with the information I need. Here is what it returns:

```
<div class=" thing id-t3_5env7c odd  link RES-keyNav-activeThing" id="thing_t3_5env7c" onclick="click_thing(this)" data-fullname="t3_5env7c" data-type="link" data-author="randy001rd" data-author-fullname="t2_rq7wc" data-subreddit="videos" data-subreddit-fullname="t5_2qh1e" data-timestamp="1479996207000" data-url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f72WZwvMTj4" data-domain="youtube.com" data-rank="1" data-context="listing">
```

What I need is the data-url and data-domain from the post that is upvoted. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `data-url` would be the `element.dataset.url` - `data-domain` would be the `element.dataset.domain` - where element is the DOM element in question

Answer (score 0):

jQuery provides a `.data` method that you can use to retrieve the fields. `$("div.arrow").parent().parent().data("url")` should give you the `data-url` field, and getting the domain is similar.

```js
alert($("div").data("url"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="thing id-t3_5env7c odd  link RES-keyNav-activeThing" id="thing_t3_5env7c" onclick="click_thing(this)" data-fullname="t3_5env7c" data-type="link" data-author="randy001rd" data-author-fullname="t2_rq7wc" data-subreddit="videos" data-subreddit-fullname="t5_2qh1e" data-timestamp="1479996207000" data-url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f72WZwvMTj4" data-domain="youtube.com" data-rank="1" data-context="listing">
```

Comment: I keep getting "Undefined" when I put in `alert($("div .arrow").parent().parent().data("url"));`

Also, any ideas on how I would go about figuring out which post I upvoted?